# Pegar informações de uma div em C#

Tags: c#, html, div, html-tags

Bem, eu tenho um código que lê a página porém eu preciso do seguinte:

```
<a href="/t848p15-teste">2</a>
```

A ideia do código é procurar por uma tag `<a>` que tenha esse `2` e retornar o link. No caso, ele iria retornar: `/t848p15-teste`.

O código que tenho para ler é este:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("site_aqui");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
string Texto = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o Html Agility Pack, que é uma biblioteca para tratar HTML.

> **Nuget: Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack**

Você deve carregar o texto HTML na classe que manipula o mesmo, e depois pode usar [XPATH](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) para procurar o elemento desejado.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(Texto);
var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(text(),'2')][@href]");

if (links != null)
{
    var primeiroLinkAchando = links.FirstOrDefault();

    if (primeiroLinkAchando != null)
    {
        var href = primeiroLinkAchando.Attributes["href"].Value;
        // agora você pode fazer o que quizer com o href
    }

    foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
    {
        var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
        // agora você pode fazer o que quizer com o href
    }
}
```

Comment: Tinha dado um erro mas tava falando um ".Attributes" em "link".

Como eu faço para pegar isso somente no primeiro resultado? Ele está pegando em todos os resultados.

Comment: No caso você pode simplesmente ignorar todos os outros resultados da lista usando o método LINQ `FirstOrDefault` por exemplo.

Comment: Arrumei a resposta... realmente faltava o `Attributes` =) foi mal!

Comment: Pode me explicar mais sobre esse método LINQ? Eu queria pegar SOMENTE o '2'.

Comment: O LINQ é um conjunto de métodos para trabalhar com listas. `FirstOrDefault` pega o primeiro elemento de uma lista e retorna ele, ou nulo, se a lista estiver vazia.

Comment: Mas acho que o que vc quer não tem que ver com o LINQ... para pegar o texto do elemento, `"2"`, você pode usar a propriedade `link.InnerText`.

Comment: Eu tentei usar o InnerText, porém os acentos ficam todos bugados com "??", procure muito na internet pra tentar resolver e parecer que não tem jeito. xD

Comment: Por isso procurei uma forma alternativa de conseguir isso.

Comment: Aqui eu não tive esse problema da acentuação. Tenta setar o encoding do HtmlDocument: `doc.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` e vê se resolve.